# Generic term for measuring time between user creating a listing and removing that listing?

Tags: terminology, selling-ux, metrics, measuring

I am measuring the time between users creating a listing and deactivating a listing to A/B test and make inferences around success (for some apps, including the one I'm working on, a *shorter* listing duration is a hint of greater success).

I am not sure of the appropriate jargon/terminology for the period of time between a user creating a listing and the time that listing is deactivated/removed?

Currently, I am calling it '**listing duration**', or '**days online**', but I made these up to describe the metric - I hope to understand if there is a more generic term/metric used by UX professionals?

Comment: I'm not aware if there is a generic term used in UX, "durability", "lifetime" or "life-cycle duration" maybe? Depends a little on the usage.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some really quick ideas. Try out searching for synonyms for keywords in thesaurus for more options.

- Active Dates
- Active Timeframe
- Listing Active for
- Listing Timespan
- Days/Time before Lapse
- Lapsed/Closed After x Days (personal favorite)